# Looping through function in R

Tags: r

Using this line of code, I can retrieve ~55 columns of details for each of the 15 games played at the AAA level in professional baseball last Friday, the 31st. Package used here is baseballr.

```r
mlb_game_pks("2023-03-31", level_ids = c(11)) -> AAA
```

One of the columns of data generated is `game_pk` which is the unique identifier of the specific game and in the code above, 15 such unique numbers are returned.

My question is how to pass through each of the 15 unique `game_pk` numbers through this line of code to then pull all of the pitch by pitch data?

```r
mlb_pbp_diff(game_pk = 722652, start_timecode = "20230331", end_timecode = "20230331") -> pbp_example
```

Note there may very well be another function in baseballr that will do this automatically by just plugging in the desired date range but I am actually trying to learn a little about looping in R using data I am familiar with.

Tried this to no avail:

Made list of game_pk's: `PKs <- list(AAA$game_pk)`

```r
for(i in PKs){
mlb_pbp_diff(i, start_timecode = "20230331", end_timecode = "20230331") -> pbp_example
}
```

Comment: `lapply(PKs, function(x) mlb_pbp_diff(game_pk = x, start_timecode = "20230331", end_timecode = "20230331"))` should give you what you need.  This is clasic  fodder for the `apply` family of functions.  The return value from the code I gave you will be a `list`, each element of which will be the result of `mlb_pbp_diff` applied to an element of `PKs`.

Comment: I've missed the boat somewhere. Keyed code as follows: lapply(PKs, function(x) mlb_pbp_diff(game_pk = x, start_timecode = "20230331", end_timecode = "20230331")) -> test3           Then received this back: Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE

Comment: I have figured this out. Thanks for nudging me in the right direction.